# Determine the argument of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the argument of function inside the log function,
$$F(z)=\ln\Big[\frac{-1}{z+a_0+i\delta}\Big]$$
where $\delta>0$ is infinitesimal, and $z+a_0>0$. I know that there is branch cut along the real axis for $z>-a_0$. I want to determine the argument of the inside function, so I can write $F(z)$ as
$$F(z)=\ln\Big|\frac{1}{z+a_0+i\delta}\Big|+i\theta$$

Comment: Write the expression inside the logarithm in the form $a+i b$ and use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your method the answer is +i$\pi$. If I try to follow the geometric picture, $-a_0-(z+i\delta)$ can be seen as vector with argument $\pi$, and inverse change $\pi$ to $-\pi$. What is wrong with this picture?

Comment: Maybe I should change $-\pi$ to $\pi$ in the end since the argument here is $[0,2\pi)$ as formula in the above link.